# HTML5 code element - language class

Tags: html

The HTML5 `<code>` element has an [optional class="language-" attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-code-element) to define the language of the code fragment. An example from the spec:

```html
<pre><code class="language-pascal">var i: Integer;
begin
   i := 1;
end.</code></pre>
```

Is there a list of the languages to be used?  Just thinking that otherwise there are likely to be multiple different spellings or interpretations of languages e.g. VB6 vs visual basic 6 etc.

Comment: It seems that there is no definition, so that any addition is allowed and probably makes no difference.

Comment: If that's definitely the case, put it as an answer and I'll give you the credit

Comment: I thinks it's more of a hint saying "hey, don't use the `lang` attribute for this, that's wrong – use a sensible `class` instead". As the specs say, there is no *formal* way of declaring the language, so there wouldn't be any formal list of "allowed" values. Such a list would most likely be formalized by whatever syntax highlighting script you're using.

Comment: I guess the question I wasn't quite asking is, "are there any defacto syntax highlighting scripts that have formalized the language descriptions for <code>"  I'm assuming the answer is no, so I'll stop digging for now :)

Comment: @KrisC highlight.js ?  http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/description/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the WHATWG’s [HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/) version of the specification, it does actually recommend prefixing the value of `class` attributes on `<code>` elements with "`language-*`":

From the [HTML Living Standard: Text-Level Semantics - the code element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-code-element:classes)

> There is no formal way to indicate the language of computer code being marked up. Authors who wish to mark code elements with the language used, e.g. so that syntax highlighting scripts can use the right rules, can use the class attribute, e.g. by adding a class prefixed with "language-" to the element.

(However, I would assume that this prefix has no real practical value – that would depend on whether real-world websites take up the convention and whether third-party tools detect and actually implement this prefix.)

Comment: Indeed. The text is very obviously just informative guidance and not intended to be treated as canon in any way.